# Could not change the form method from "post" to "delete"

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working for the first time with the Symfony framework and I am facing an issue which I could not resolve by my own.

I have 2 actions in my class and they are having the same route.
I want that the first get executed when the route method requirement is of type "GET" and the second when the method is of type "DELETE".

To call the second action I made a form element and modified it to so I can get the "DELETE" method.

However the form it is still pointing to the wrong action.

Could you see where I made a mistake ?

1- this is a portion of my template

```
{% for property in properties %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{property.title}}</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{{path('admin.property.edit', {id : property.id})}}">Editer</a>
                <form method="post" action="{{path('admin.property.delete', {id: property.id})}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token('delete'~ property.id)}}">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Supprimer</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

2- These are the actions:

```
/**
 * @Route("admin/biens/{id}", name="admin.property.edit")
 */
    public function edit(Property $property, Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(PropertyType::class, $property);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
        {
            $this->em->persist($property);
            $this->em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin.property.index');

        }

        return $this->render('admin/edit.html.twig',[
            'property' => $property,
             'form' =>$form->createView()
        ]);
    }

/**
 * @Route("admin/biens/{id}", name="admin.property.delete", methods={"DELETE"})
 */
    public function delete(Property $property, Request $request)
    {
        $submittedToken = $request->request->get('_token');
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$property->getId(), $submittedToken)) {

            $this->em->remove($property);
            $this->em->flush();

        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin.property.index');

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set methods in the first route :

```
/**
 * @Route("admin/biens/{id}", name="admin.property.edit", methods={"GET, POST"})
 */
```

See the symfony documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/requirements.html#adding-http-method-requirements